# i want to develop core of my project in doctrine and php and use codeigniter to acces it as webservice. any good ideas?

Tags: codeigniter, orm, doctrine

basically what i am trying to develop is core of my project in doctrine ORM with custom php, and then use codeigniter to access it as web service, ios, android, desktop applications. any suggestions how to get start. i have designed all my entites.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you [joelverhagen blog post](http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/) where you can find codeigniter and doctrine2 from scratch. 
This is the very [basic](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup)
[small one](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2)

NB:Also if you are thinking of switching to ODM-Object Document Model(if you use nosql) you can see [this](http://neal-anders.com/blog/archives/229)